Break multi-target dependencies over several lines in Makefile
This question, and the corresponding answers, describe how to break up dependencies into multiple lines. That is, either (1) use a backslash, (2) specify the target line multiple times with different dependencies in each, or (3) populate a variable containing the dependencies and specify the target line once.
What about for the case of multiple targets, either independent or grouped? The answer seems to be clear for options 1 and 3, but what about for option 2? Do we do something like this?:
target1 target2: dep1
target1 target2: dep2

Or, in the case of grouped targets:
target1 target2 &: dep1
target1 target2 &: dep2


Yes, that's how you do it.
